# How is the pointer (*) making changes in the following code?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The following program is intended to check if a given element is in a given array, indices of array where the element occurs and number of times the element occurs. But, it doesn't give right results. I tried to replace `poscount` in seqsearch function with `*poscount` and did further changes for this pointer data type. Then the code works well. Why this is so?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 100;
void seqsearch(int[], int, int, int[], short);

int main() {
    int array[SIZE], indices[SIZE];
    int num, value;
    short count = 0;
    cerr << " Give number of elements in array : ";
    cin >> num;
    cerr << " Key in the array elements ";
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) cin >> array[i];
    cout << endl;
    cerr << " Give the value to be searched : " << endl;
    cin >> value;
    cout << endl;
    seqsearch(array, num, value, indices, count); // void function
    if(count >= 0) {
        cout << value << " found in array " << count << " times"
             << " at index positions " << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) cout << indices[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    } else
        cout << value << " not found in array " << endl;
    return 0;
}

void seqsearch(int arr[], int size, int elm, int pos[], short poscount) {
    int i, item;
    poscount = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == elm) {
            pos[poscount] = i;
            poscount = poscount + 1;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `seqsearch` is supposed to return the result in `pos` and `poscount`, but the function takes `poscount` *by-value* which means that any changes you make to `poscount` inside the function, will be local to the function and not visible from the call site.

If you change the function to take the argument *by-reference*, the changes you make inside the function will actually be made to the variable used in the call to the function. Like this:

```
seqsearch(int arr[], int size, int elm, int pos[], short& poscount) // note short&
```

The `int pos[]` does not have the same problem because arrays *decay* into pointers, so it could have been `int* pos` instead - and that pointer points at the same array that you passed in at the call site.

---

Also note that the check after the call will make the program display "found in array" even if it isn't found in the array because the condition checks if `count` is zero or greater than zero.

```
    if(count >= 0) {   // should be  if(count > 0) {
```

---

---

Suggestions unrelated to the problem in your question:

- When the number of elements is not known at the time you compile your program, prefer to use a container which can grow dynamically, like a `std::vector<int>`. In your program you have a hardcoded limit of `SIZE` number of elements, but:

  - You will rarely use all of them.
  - You do not check if the user wants to enter more than `SIZE` elements and your program will gladly try to write out of bounds - which would cause [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).
- Divide the program's subtasks into functions. It'll be easier to search for bugs if you can test each individual function separately.
- Check that extracting values from `std::cin` actually succeeds.

  ```
  int number;
  if(std::cin >> number) { /* success */ } else { /* failure */ }
  ```
- Check that the values entered makes sense too.

  ```
  int wanted_container_elements;
  if(std::cin >> wanted_container_elements && wanted_container_elements > 0) {
      /* success */ 
  } else {
      /* failure */ 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

`poscount` (or `count` in the context of the caller) in your code seems to be expected to be an output parameter.

To modify the passed value you must either have its address (a pointer) or a reference to the value.
Currently you are using "pass-by-value", meaning that `poscount` is a copy of `count`.
The original `count` stays untouched.

My personal favorite would be to return the value instead of using an out-parameter:

```
short seqsearch(int arr[], int size, int elm, int pos[]) {
    int i, item;
    short poscount = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == elm) {
            pos[poscount] = i;
            poscount = poscount + 1;
        }
    }
    return poscount;
}
```

```
    count = seqsearch(array, num, value, indices);
```

Alternatively you can use a reference to manipulate the out-parameter:

```
void seqsearch(int arr[], int size, int elm, int pos[], short& poscount) {
    int i, item;
    poscount = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == elm) {
            pos[poscount] = i;
            poscount = poscount + 1;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

```
    seqsearch(array, num, value, indices, count);
```

And, as you already tried, you can also solve this by passing a pointer to the value:

```
void seqsearch(int arr[], int size, int elm, int pos[], short* poscount) {
    int i, item;
    *poscount = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == elm) {
            pos[*poscount] = i;
            *poscount = *poscount + 1;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

```
    seqsearch(array, num, value, indices, &count);
```

Comment: double check your value return eg. This one is the best solution and you should put it first. The code seems to have a bug though, you are returning nothing.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Thanks - Looks like I had copied an old version. Corrected

Comment: Secondly, before you can have an upvote. The pointer edition of the function is incorrect. If you pass a pointer to a function as an output parameter, it is because you expect it to be optional, aka, i can pass NULL. What happens if you pass nullptr to that function?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I have to disagree that this assumption can always be taken. Especially in a world where you often work with C-style code you can not assume a pointer to be meant optional. Also, what about C-style arrays? But yes, if a parameter can be null it should be checked as well. I will add a short hint to this to my answer later on, as it also applies to `arr` and `pos` in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass your posscount argument, you pass a copy to the count variable in main, not the variable itself. That's why it works, when you pass it by pointer. You can also pass by reference. https://www.includehelp.com/cpp-tutorial/argument-passing-with-its-types.aspx